# change a variable value according to others variables values in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I want to change(or keep) a value of my dataframe according to the values of other variables in the same data frame. I've been looking for and answer without much success. This is an example of the database I have:

```
    date    day VM  id
12/01/2013  4   133 1
12/01/2013  4   163 1
13/01/2013  5   143 1
13/01/2013  5   123 1
14/01/2013  6   90  1
14/01/2013  6   190 1
15/01/2013  7   922 1
15/01/2013  7   952 1
16/01/2013  1   13  1
16/01/2013  1   25  1
17/01/2013  2   333 1
17/01/2013  2   123 1
18/01/2013  3   143 1
18/01/2013  3   169 1
19/01/2013  4   203 1
19/01/2013  4   133 1
```

each number represents a day (1:Monday, 2:tuesday,...)and each day has hundreds of data, also the information is for 8 days so there will be one day repeated ( but in a different date). When I apply summary it gives me the info mixing the data of the repeated day and I want to avoid that, My idea is to change the last day of use (the repeated one) to the number 8 but the repeated day change by id and I've got plenty of data. So far I've tried this:

```
unicos<-unique(data$id)
 data_corr<-NULL
 for(j in 1:length(unicos))
  subset<-data[which(data$id==unicos[j]),]
  subset$day1<-NULL
  times<-0
  vector<-NULL

  for(i in 1:(dim(subset)[1])){
    if((subset$day[i]<-subset$day[1]) && if (subset$date[i]<-subset$date[1])){
        vector<-c(vector, i)
        times<-times+1
        subset$day1[i]<-subset$day[1]   
    }
    subset$day1<-8  
  }
  Basal_corr<-rbind(Basal_corr, subset)
}
```

The first "for" is meant to apply the conditions one id at the time. The second part is the hard one. What I want to do is that if the day in the row [i] is in, is the same that the one in the first row (since it is the one that is going to repeat) then go check the date, if the date is the same too I want to keep keep the original day value in a new column called day1, and if the date is different then day1 value will be 8. I use Basal_corr<-rbind(Basal_corr, subset) to keep track of all the changes made by id. I get an "ERROR" everytime I try to run it, and I really  don't know whats grong I'm an R newbie and this is beyond what I know till now.

Comment: Do the actual numbers have to be the same. If you just need to differentiate them with a an integer you can just do `data$new <- as.numeric(data$date)`.

Comment: Or, if you want the same numbers, but just need an 8 for the last day, and these are the only dates you have, you can try  `df$new <- df$date ; levels(df$new) <- c(4,5,6,7,1,2,3,8)`

Comment: Why not just aggregate on the date????????

Comment: Thanks @SimonO101 but can I do it(the second one) if the numbers from 1-7 are completely aleatorized? What i mean is that there aren't always 4,5,6,7,1,2,3, they can be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. 2,3,4,5,6,7, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe

> each number represents a day (1:Monday, 2:tuesday,...)and each day has
>   hundreds of data, also the information is for 8 days so there will be
>   one day repeated ( but in a different date).

is actually the definition of a Julian date.  This function is included in base R.  I don't think you need any loops, it's just 2 lines of code.  FYI- R operates with vectors, so a function refers to the whole vector/column of values at the same time.

```
Days$date <- as.Date(Days$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y") 
Days$day <- julian(Days$date) - julian(Days$date[1]) + 1
Days # yields

# date day  VM id
# 1  2013-01-12   1 133  1
# 2  2013-01-12   1 163  1
# 3  2013-01-13   2 143  1
# 4  2013-01-13   2 123  1
# 5  2013-01-14   3  90  1
# 6  2013-01-14   3 190  1
# 7  2013-01-15   4 922  1
# 8  2013-01-15   4 952  1
# 9  2013-01-16   5  13  1
# 10 2013-01-16   5  25  1
# 11 2013-01-17   6 333  1
# 12 2013-01-17   6 123  1
# 13 2013-01-18   7 143  1
# 14 2013-01-18   7 169  1
# 15 2013-01-19   8 203  1
# 16 2013-01-19   8 133  1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for, I solved my question quite differently but your answer really seems like the best to do in a future situtation like that.